# How can I get stderr from os.popen()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I call

```
os.popen('foo').read()
```

I want to capture

```
sh: foo: not found
```

as well.
I don't have the `subprocess` module since this is a minimal install on an embedded system.

popen3,4 doesn't work either:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 667, in popen3
import subprocess
ImportError: No module named subprocess
```

I suppose I could do

```
os.popen(command + " 2>&1").read()
```

to pipe it to stdout, but ideally I'd want to get it separately.

Comment: Use `os.popen4()`; it returns a tuple with `child_stdin, child_stderr`.  You could also use `popen3()` which returns `child_stdin, child_stdout, child_stderr`.  **Disclaimer**: I think.

Comment: Those are wrappers for subprocess.

Comment: What about piping to a real file and then opening that?

Comment: I don't know about embedded systems but if you've got Python, you've got filesystem rw, right?

Comment: @cat, or just named pipe may be

Comment: You could even pipe it to another character device in `/dev/tty` and `open` that

Comment: @DmitryNarkevich: They are, but `os.popen()` isn't?

Comment: @zondo `os.popen()` is a system call, not a wrapper -- subprocess would be preferred here

Answer (score 3):

Since subprocess should be use in place of os.popen, you can do something like that

test.py:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

p = Popen("foo", shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print "stdout: '%s'" % stdout
print "stderr: '%s'" % stderr
```

Now execute:

```
python test.py 
stdout: ''
stderr: '/bin/sh: 1: foo: not found
'
```

Notice the CR in stderr.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate as to why it is better?

Comment: @user2589273, (1) allows operating without a shell, which cures a series of security issues; (2) _whether or not_ operating without a shell, allows arguments to be passed out-of-band from the code being run, which lets someone write secure code even while using a shell (albeit requiring some effort). (3) offers vastly more flexibility -- lets one run a process in a different directory, perform redirections, control status of file descriptors, etc. (4) preferred as the replacement by upstream Python; as the current upstream docs say: ...

Comment: @user2589273, "*This is implemented using subprocess.Popen; see that class’s documentation for more powerful ways to manage and communicate with subprocesses*" -- so right now `os.popen` is just a less-powerful wrapper around `subprocess.Popen`; use the `subprocess` module and you get the full power.